# How to check installed program version?

Tags: command-line

How can I check installed program versions in terminal. Is there any command for that, for example **ver** or something similar?

Answer (score 30, accepted):

The way how to know version of an installed package varies for different programs. Usually

```
application_name --version
```

or

```
application_name -version
```

can be used to know it. It is better to see `man application_name` and search which is the command line switch to know the version.

If you installed any package using `apt`, to see the version you can try

```
apt-cache policy package_name
```

In few cases the version can be found in `application_name --help`. For example `virtualbox`

In few very little case `application_name -v` also gives you version.

Comment: thnx, it was very helpful :)

Comment: `package_name --version` is not usually, it's a standard, so it must to work with any package.

Comment: `package_name -v` is also not usually. It works only for a small number of programs. See `gedit -v`, `ls -l`, `chromium-browser -v`, `grep -v`, `sed -v`, etc. So I think that is not a good advice at all.

Comment: Thanks @RaduRădeanu for correcting me. I meant to say application, but written package by mistake. Edited, plz check once.

Comment: @souravc It doesn't make any difference. See `google-chrome -v` or `chromium-browser -v`. And any application is a program for me. See also http://unix.stackexchange.com/q/2645/37944.